# Lee Yang force and cosmology

Tags: general-relativity, forces, cosmology

The text I am reading (Stars and Relativity by Ya. B. Zel'dovich) discusses the possible existence of a repulsive force proportional to total baryon number. At the time of the book's publication it was stated that if such a force existed, it woukd need to be on the order of $10^{46}$ times weaker than the Coulomb force between two protons.

It's also stated as a footnote that such a force would be incompatible with a homogeneous, isotropic universe.  Why is this so? Has any of the above changed in the ~40 years since this text was published?

Comment: [This chap](http://arxiv.org/find/gr-qc/1/au:+Hsu_J/0/1/0/all/0/1) has written a few papers related to the Lee-Yang force. I can't find any other recent activity. [This book](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789812703408_fmatter) mentions it briefly in the context of the development of Yang-Mills theory.